# Ways to use steamworks sdk functions (c++) in python?

Tags: python, c++, steam, steamworks-api

steamworks sdk contains .lib file, dll, headers folder and sdk folder.
From all this functions i need only small amount of them, like SteamUser()->InitiateGameConnection() in python, becouse no one python library contains something like this (i don't found it)

Comment: If there isn't something already in python, you'll have to create python bindings through custom C APIs to bridge between. There are some libraries/utilities out there to help simplify this type of process as well, such as SWIG

Comment: You can also take a look at the existing work that's been done on [SteamWorks for Python](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/api#thirdparty).

Comment: @NathanPierson, if you mean steamworks-py, i used this and don't found similar function